# Space in left sidebar (wrong transform: calculate) on semantic ui

Tags: vue.js, semantic-ui

I'm trying to use [Semantic-UI sidebar](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html) .. But it is always displayed an  empty space on right in sidebar: **See the grey area...**

[image]

- For iPads (landscape) and computers (screens larger than 640px): Show sidebar
- For mobiles or ipads (widescape) (screens smaller than 640px): hide and display sidebar menu

But it is always displayed an empty space when the screen is larger than 640px.

The sidebar has a width of 101px, but seeing the css is calculating how 260px.. in chrome dev tools `transform: translate3d(260px,0,0);`

Source here..  http://www.webpackbin.com/N1hpsz92Z

Comment: `Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList': The token provided ('blue image label') contains HTML space characters, which are not valid in tokens.`